# Windows DHCP server not sending all options

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp-server

I'm facing a strange problem with Windows Server 2003 and its DHCP server. Here is my scope and its related options.

[image: DHCP scope options]

However when I look at the traffic using Wireshark, here is what the server is really sending:

```
Option: (53) DHCP Message Type
Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
Option: (1) Subnet Mask
Option: (81) Client Fully Qualified Domain Name
Option: (15) Domain Name
Option: (3) Router
Option: (6) Domain Name Server
Option: (255) End
```

As you can see, option number `191` is missing from the list. This is a custom string option I added by I had the same problem with option *44: WINS Servers*, not showing in the list.

I rebooted the server and checked any option but I can't tell why this is happening.

Comment: Your VLAN ID is showing as 0x2E - I'm pretty sure it should look similar to [this](http://www.ipbalance.com/images/stories/users/DHCP_Nortel_IP_Phone_setup3.png)

Comment: @Cole `VLAN-A:46.` though I'd still expect it to send the data, even if the option was configured incorrectly

Comment: @Dan makes me wonder if the phone isn't sending out a DHCP request first.

Comment: Could you add what Wireshark sees in the DHCPR DISCOVER and/or REQUEST as Parameter Request List?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen this is a old request and I don't have access to this anymore so I cannot fulfill your request. I don't recall how I solved this issue.